# terminal command line python3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following a book tutorial and it's telling me to install python3.3 with the command line

```
sudo apt-get install python3.3
```

however I'm getting errors

```
Unable to locate package python3.3
Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.3;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3

Just install python3.2.3.  As given below

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```