# Installing distribute for Python 3.3

Tags: python, ubuntu, pymongo, distribute

I try to install distribute with python 3.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 to install pymongo.

I downloaded distribute_setup.py with

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
```

Afterwards I tried

```
python3 distribute_setup.py install
```

But I recive

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.49.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 556, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 552, in main
    tarball = download_setuptools(download_base=options.download_base)
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 211, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 156, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 475, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 587, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 507, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 692, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 469, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 492, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 1310, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Can someone please help me? It seems as if distribute uses code, that does not compile with python 3.3..

I installed Python 3.3.2 in my homefolder following these steps:

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

If I try to install pymongo from source I recive:

```
Extracting in /tmp/tmpth91z4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, Feature
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/pymongo/ez_setup.py", line 130, in use_setuptools
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 25, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "/home/dev/pymongo/ez_setup.py", line 132, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/dev/pymongo/ez_setup.py", line 111, in _do_download
    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
  File "/home/dev/pymongo/ez_setup.py", line 83, in _build_egg
    tar = tarfile.open(tarball)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/tarfile.py", line 1571, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

Thank you

Comment: Seems like your Python installation does not have SSL support.

Comment: I installed Python 3.3.2 from the Python homepage. Openssl is also installed. build-essential
libncursesw5-dev
libreadline5-dev
libssl-dev
libgdbm-dev
libc6-dev
libsqlite3-dev
tk-dev and zlib1g-dev are also installed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050987/terminal-command-line-python3-3/16051077#16051077

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you installed `openssl-devel` before compiling Python? I have had the same issue, however I fixed it by previously installing `openssl-devel` and then compiling Python 3 + distribute.

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu it is libssl-dev package